# Programmatically modifying layer datasource on project save event?

Tags: qgis, wms, qgis-plugins, wfs, pyqgis

I have a QGIS plugin which allows users to add WFS/WMS layers to the map.

I would like to be able to scramble the user ID part (token) of the uri when the project is saved/closed and then use my own instance of QgsProjectBadLayerHandler to fix the uri when a project is opened. The result being that only users with the plugin and correct access levels are able to to view the WMS/WFS layers, so if a qgis project file is opened by someone without the plugin they will be unable to loads the layers.

I am having no luck changing the uri when the project is saved. Here is what I have so far:

```
self.project.projectSaved.connect(self.project_saved)
self.project = QgsProject.instance()

...

def project_saved(self):
    reg = self.LoginAndStore.check_reg()
    token = str(reg[1])
    toc = self.iface.legendInterface()
    toc_layers = toc.layers()
    for layer in toc_layers:
        try:
            dp = layer.dataProvider()
            src = str(dp.dataSourceUri())
            if token in src:
                no_token = src.replace(token, "NOTOKEN")
                dp.setDataSourceUri(no_token)
                #dp.reloadData()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
    f = QFileInfo(r"C:\Users\me\Documents\testing.qgs")
    self.project.write(f)
```

How do I get this working or are there other methods to prevent unauthorized access?

Comment: What if someone guessed your WFS URL? Is the WFS server protected by some sort of authentication?

Comment: Yeah I would just use normal user name and passwords for this.  Any other solution will be a hack.

Comment: @til_b The user logs in via the plugin and a unique token is provided for there wfs/wms url's. So its impossible to guess. The problem is if they save a project with wfs/wms in and pass it on to someone else can also view the layers.

Comment: I would think that this can not be solved without having a user provide a password. You need it to work with user1 at machine1, but deny access to user2 at machine1. So you cannot restrict by client machine. So you need to restrict by something that is specific to the user. Such as a password.